# Who introduced the term "Stress" in mechanics?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, stresses

I know that Cauchy introduced the idea of stress in 1822 via the Cauchy tetrahedron, did he term it too ?

Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy was French, so probably not. Term "stress" was used earlier for example by Peter Barlow in "[AN ESSAY ON THE STRENGTH AND STRESS OF TIMBER](https://www.ebay.com.my/itm/114818270735?hash=item1abbb3c60f:g:%7E3UAAOSwFe1gps9N)" (1817). You may find many references and interesting details in Timoshenko's [History of Strength of Materials](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/238240.History_of_Strength_of_Materials). One of the references where you might find the answer is Todhunter's "[A History of the Theory of Elasticity and of the Strength of Materials: From Galilei to the Present Time](https://www-cambridge-org.ezproxy.lib.vutbr.cz/core/books/history-of-the-theory-of-elasticity-and-of-the-strength-of-materials/F1F62FAC50BB14FF166D16F337210744)".

Comment: thanks. I did skim through history of strength of materials, but couldn't find additional info than what i said above.

Comment: @Mechanician I suspect this information will be quite difficult to find, because many people before Cauchy definitely had some inaccurate notion of "stress", at least in form of pressure (Euler, Bernoulli, Newton). Most of them, not being English, would not use "stress", so you should be looking at something which would be directly translated as "stress". The term "work" for example was coined by [Coriolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspard-Gustave_de_Coriolis) as "travail" in original since he was French.